# Send all data from inputs in a form through email without defining each field

Tags: html, forms

I have like 150+ forms with different input IDs. I need to collect all the data from the inputs and send them over through email directly without defining those fields. I see that the site https://formspree.io/ has that feature but I want to know how I can implement that myself. Thank you!

This how the site handles the form:

```
<form action="//formspree.io/your@email.com"
      method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="_replyto">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

This allows all inputs to be sent directly to the given email.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got the answer.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    $body .= $key . ' -> ' . $value . '<br>';
```

Comment: Kinda. Be sure to sanitize that data prior to putting it into an e-mail, or it will be possible for an attacker to direct outgoing mail (spam) through your server using injection technique.